# Inheritance of component angular 6 templates

Tags: html, templates, inheritance, angular6

We know we can extend an angular component but I would like to also extend the template associated. I mean, for instance, I could define an abstract component with its template with kind of skeleton, and then in the children would be forced to implements not only the abstract class methods and so on, but also the "empty gaps" of the skeleton html template.

Up to now, I have to completely redefine the template in the child.
I know that I could create another component but that a relationship by association. It's annoying because I have to create an abstract class to be extend and then a component to redefine the template.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. What could be useful to you is content projection

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Comment: Thank you, I think the "select" atribute of ng-content does exactly what I wanted, as we can pass more than one "ng-contents" to the same component and we can fill the "skeleton" the way we want. Thanks again!

Comment: Would it also be possible for the outer component and the content component to interact? In particular, would the outer component be able to enforce that the content component must implement a certain TypeScript interface, and/or would the content component be able to "privately" access certain members of the outer component that only the outer component's content is privvy to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-content` and `ng-template`.

In your *abstract* component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'abstract-component',
  template: /*html*/`
    <abstract-template>
      <div>
        <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="customTemplate || defaultTemplate"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </abstract-template>

    <ng-template #defaultTemplate>
      ... default HTML ...
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
```

then in your new component, where you want to adjust or customise the template, you should add:

```
<abstract-template
  ... inputs ...
>
  <ng-template #customTemplate>
    ... your custom HTML ...
  </ng-template>
</abstract-template>
```

`ngTemplateOutlet` will pick the customTemplate if it is passed through `ng-template`